# Jquery UI Datepicker use 2 dateformats

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a client that need next:

Use a datepicker widget, that supports two different dateformats?

Ex:
`dd/mm/yy` and `dd-mm-yy`

Is this possible with jQuery UI? Maybe with another plugin?

Thanks for the help

Comment: This does not make any logical sense. When would you use one or the other?

Comment: There is a way to do it, since it's an `option`, you can change the format. You just can't use both at the same time. You could make a toggle switch in the button panel to use different formats.

Comment: Like so: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats ?

Comment: I don't think that this may be usefull.. but client wants the datepickers make this :) I was thinking about a toogle, but will cause a lot of conditions to control the changes in middle of a manual change and dirty code :S

Comment: Ok, so under what conditions do they need the resulting date that is picked to have which format?